# mui-datatables custom header with multiple buttons position

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

in my app I'm working with mui-datatables. I added a custom toolbar to the table with one additional button, which is added into the row with the other buttons. But when I add a second button, it gets added below, although there is enough space. How can I display the second button in the row with the other ones?

[image: example]

```
  const HeaderElements = () => (
    <>
      <AddNewButton />
      <ExportJsonButton />
    </>
  );

  <MUIDataTable
    title=""
    data={rows}
    columns={columns}
    options={{
      selectableRowsHeader: false,
      selectableRowsHideCheckboxes: true,
      customToolbar: () => (<HeaderElements />),
    }}
   />
```

Comment: Could you please share a simple sample of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: It is interesting, in the codesandbox it's working with just normal buttons https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-haze-vvcm1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself:  has to be wrapped in a Button:

```
<Button>
  <AddNewButton />
</Button>
```